# Create or delete a folder using FSO

Tags: javascript, vbscript, fso

Is there an FSO (file system object) method to create or delete a folder in JavaScript or VBScript? Any other JavaScript or VBScript method to create or delete a folder which works in HTA is also accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the [CreateFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kby5ae3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and the [DeleteFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca0at0xh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)